# Log4j.xml dynamic file attributes

Tags: java, log4j

I am deploying my application in websphere server and i want to set param File attribute of log4j.xml. Locally i am doing like

```
<param name="File" value="C:\\logs\\cle_error.log" />
```

My server name is App_Admin and path where i want to generate debug.log file is /waslib/appadmin/uat/logs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use System property for this like:

```
<param name="File" value="${mylog.path}" />
```

And when you start your application, you could just pass system property like:

```
java -Dmylog.path="/waslib/appadmin/uat/logs" ...
```